# Sonar scan says Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause

Tags: java, file, sonarqube, try-with-resources

Sonar qube is giving me the following error:

> Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause

This is my code:

```
Path start = Paths.get(filePath);
Stream<File> stream;
try {
    stream = Files.walk(start, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).map(s -> s.toFile());
    List<File> files = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
                    files.remove(0);
                    for (File f : files) {
                        String fileName = f.toPath().getFileName().toString();
                        if (fileName.matches(regex)) {
                            fileList.add(f.toPath().toString());
                        }
                    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define and open your stream this way:

```
try (Stream<File> stream = Files.walk(start, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).map(s -> s.toFile())){
```

Doing this, the system will automatically close the stream and you don't need to worry about it

Answer (score 2):

Expanding from what Ryan said, I prefer to keep the scope of the stream that's to be closed as small as possible:

```
try (Stream<File> stream = Files.walk(start, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
    List<File> files = stream
            .map(s -> s.toFile())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

That said, you stream, collect to a list, then loop some more. That can be improved:

```
try (Stream<File> stream = Files.walk(start, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
    stream
            .skip(1) // replacement of files.remove(0)
            // leave out converting to File
            .filter(f -> f.getFileName().toString().matches(regex)) // filter in the stream
            .map(Path::toString)
            .forEach(fileList::add);
}
```

I don't really like that `fileList::add`, so if you can collect to a `List<String>` and assign that to `fileList` that would be preferred. Or perhaps collect to a `List<String>` and then use `fileList.addAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Close the stream in case it will throw an exception while the stream is opened.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path start = Paths.get("");
    Stream<File> stream = null;
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        stream = Files.walk(start, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).map(s -> s.toFile());
        List<File> files = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        files.remove(0);
        for (File f : files) {
            String fileName = f.toPath().getFileName().toString();
            if (fileName.matches("")) {
                fileList.add(f.toPath().toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something
    }finally {
        if(stream!=null)
            stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely try-with-resources is better, like what Ryan initially posted? No unnecessary null assignment or check, and if the closing of the stream would throw an exception it won't replace any exception thrown from the try body.